# IIS Express won't serve up ASMX web services

Tags: asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

For some unknown reason, IIS Express is refusing to serve up ASMX web services. Instead, I get the following error:

```
HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.
```

I'm running a site using ASP.NET 2.0 on the Classic app pool (it's an old existing site, with third party DLLs that don't play well with the Integrated app pool). I don't think it matters any, but the site is also set to allow an HTTPS binding via the "SSL Enabled" setting in Visual Studio. I've verified the framework installations are correct via aspnet_regiis without any change.

Comment: What is the 'requested content' that 'appears to be a script' exactly did you say?

Comment: This error shows up when I just try to browse to the ASMX service in any browser.

Comment: Both the subject and the question say IIS Express...

Comment: Just double-checking, since I generally haven't seen people talk about things like aspnet_regiis or application pools or pipeline mode when using IIS Express. I know there's stuff in the IIS Express config file, but most people I've seen (including myself) only use IISExpress in Visual Studio without having to deal much with the configuration.

Comment: I found this: http://forums.iis.net/post/1914412.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that since the site was also making use of the older Ajax Extensions, there was a modification to the web.config file that was breaking the default handlers within IIS Express:

```
<handlers>
    <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0"/>
    <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="Microsoft.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, Microsoft.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</handlers>
```

I got rid of the "remove" line, and that solved the problem.

Comment: In my case, removing `<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />` did the trick